# Javascript Raphael animations not showing

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have this function

```
function generateCircles2(){
    for(var i = 1; i<500; i++){
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    var circle = paper.circle(-50,position,size);
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 2000;
    circle.attr("fill", "#000000");
    var cirAni = Raphael.animate({cy: position, cx: 850}, time);
    circle.animate(cirAni.delay(100));
  }
}
```

which is suppose to generate circles to move across the screen at random points, however the circles do not appear and it also stops other animations from happening over the top of these ones. How can I get these circles to move across randomly whilst keeping the other animations going at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the correct method is 'animation' and not 'animate' for an animation object (as opposed to animating an element).

So instead of

```
var cirAni = Raphael.animate({cy: position, cx: 850}, time);
```

Switch to

```
var cirAni = Raphael.animation({cy: position, cx: 850}, time);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29otha4L/)